# Modify value by key

Tags: vba

```
Dim dFeat As Collection
Set dFeat = New Collection

Dim cObj As Collection
Set cObj = New Collection
cObj.Add 3, "PASSED"
cObj.Add 4, "TOTAL"
dFeat.Add cObj, "M1"

Set cObj = New Collection
cObj.Add 5, "PASSED"
cObj.Add 6, "TOTAL"
dFeat.Add cObj, "M2"

dFeat("M1")("TOTAL") = 88 ' Error here
Debug.Print dFeat("M1")("TOTAL")
```

How do I modify the value of inner collection using the key?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Alex K.'s advice about using a `Dictionary` is correct, but I think the issue here is more general than his answer lets on. A `Collection` key (or index position for that matter) is only good for reading, not writing.

So in this line:

```
dFeat("M1")("TOTAL") = 88 ' Error here
```

`dFeat("M1")` is fine. It returns the `Collection` you added with key "M1". The error is happening because you try to directly assign to an element of *that* collection. In general, if `c` is a `Collection`, `c("TOTAL")` (or `c(2)`) can't be an lvalue.

As Alek K. says, the best way around this is to use a `Dictionary` for the inner "collections", or for both the inner and outer. Here is how using one for the inner would look:

```
Dim d As Dictionary
Set d = New Dictionary

d("PASSED") = 3
d("TOTAL") = 4

dFeat.Add d, "M1"
```

Then the line:

```
dFeat("M1")("TOTAL") = 88
```

will work because `dFeat("M1")("TOTAL")` *is* a valid lvalue.

If for some reason you can't or don't want to include the MS Scripting Runtime, you'll have to replace the failing line with something like:

```
Dim c As Collection
Set c = dFeat("M1")

Call c.Remove("TOTAL")
Call c.Add(88, "TOTAL")
```

or more concisely:

```
Call dFeat("M1").Remove("TOTAL")
Call dFeat("M1").Add(88, "TOTAL")
```

Then, you can *read* the value of `dFeat("M1")("TOTAL")`, but you still can't assign to it.

Comment: +1 for `A Collection key (or index position for that matter) is only good for reading, not writing`. Brushing off some very rusty VBA for a project and this was key (ha!) - replacing the entire item with a new object did the trick. In my case, this meant a new array filled with values from the existing array + changes. Probably a more performant way for large objects, but I'm only dealing with a few dozen arrays with 2 values each.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot update a value type in a collection;

```
Dim c as new Collection
c.add 42, "wth"
c("wth") = 88 //will error also
```

Add a reference to the Microsoft Scripting runtime, replace `Collection` with `Dictionary` & it should work.